# What's the point of the --without option in bundle install?

Tags: ruby, bundler

If your app doesn't need the gems in a certain group, why can't you just let bundler install them with a regular `bundle install`, and then simply not use them? Is it just a cleanliness issue - i.e. not installing extra things you don't need - or can it break something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem like a *cleanliness* issue only, but it is a *performance* issue, and potentially an *overhead* issue, as I will explain:

- **Cleanliness** you covered, less gems in the filesystem. Less network traffic usage ( which might be costly for some, who knows ).
- **Performance** involves reducing the time it takes to bundle and deploy your application. Saving a few milliseconds or seconds can sometimes matter in a production environment.
- **Overhead** is the least likely reason. `Bundler` will only `require` gems from the `:default` group automatically, unless you specify other groups in your `Bundler.require` statement.

*Performance* more than *Cleanliness* or *Overhead* seems to be the best reason for `--without`

---

Using the `--without` parameter is also "remembered" by `Bundler`, so be mindful of that. It's designed to be "set and forget" on the destination environment.

Reference: http://bundler.io/v1.9/groups.html